# install mysql5.7.18 on centos7

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm almost crazy, I installed mysql5.7.18 on centos（Free installation）, follow the official manual steps to install, but when i run

```
/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

The error occurred

```
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/VM_51_206_centos.pid).
```

I tried a lot of online methods, such as modify the directory permissions, etc., but the error still exists, which big brother can help out?

Comment: What version of Centos are you using. If it is the latest version, you should be using systemd to launch mysql i.e "systemctl start mysql" You can then use "systemctl journalctl -l mysql" to get information about any issues that are causing the startup to fail.

Comment: the Version is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core), but when i executed systemctlstatus mysql.server, but i seemed got nothing useful.

Comment: i installed mysql5.6.36 just now ,but i got the same problem,and i found that when i executed bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &, it didn't work in the background, and then i clicked the keyboard ,it occured this "[1]+  Exit 1                  bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
^C
", I do not know if this is the reason